# Why would a website want to know what operating system you are using?

Tags: privacy, web-browser

As [per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228256/operating-system-from-user-agent-http-header), websites can learn what operating system a client is running by examining the HTTP headers. There are some addons that prevent this from working. What is a legitimate use of this, aside from targeted marketing?

Comment: It could be used to serve the right website (css, js, fonts etc...).

Comment: @HamZa could you explain what you are thinking?

Comment: For example, I would serve a different site to an Android device than a Windows or OS X device. This could even vary between the versions of the same OS, for example https://css-tricks.com/os-specific-fonts-css/

Answer (score 8):

One obvious answer is when the website contains applications that you can download - it can then offer the content appropriate for your operating system. If I go to `www.videolan.org` with Javascript turned off, the download link goes to the Windows binary, but if I turn Javascript on, it goes to the appropriate binary for the system I'm actually using.

Comment: wait just with js off they dont get Your OS anymore? I thought the OS is also included in the UserAgent...

Comment: Another reason is for device fingerprinting

Comment: @Purefan well ya, that's what I mean a legitimate use.

Comment: @My1: UserAgent header is a tragic piece of history, and getting any sort of useful data out is a pain. Using JS is significantly simpler.

Comment: but especially on mobile using UA is easier, becsause you dont even want to know how often I saw sites (especially forums and stuff) where I couldnt even use the js-powered submit button just because the js failed to load over mobile internet...